# Showing $f\colon \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\rightarrow(-\infty,+\infty), f(x)=x+\tan{x}$ is surjective.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How to prove surjectivity of the function $f$?
$$f\colon \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\rightarrow (-\infty,+\infty), \quad f(x)=x+\tan{x}$$
I cannot express $x$ as the number whose function is an arbitrary real number $y$.
If possible, I do not want to claim $f$ is continuous in the domain, so as to calculate the limits of the function when $x$ tends to $\pi/2$ or $-\pi/2$.

Comment: By curiosity... Why don't you want to invoke continuity and limits? That would be easy!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: You don't have to use that the function strictly increasing (or increasing at all), but I don't see an easy way to get out of using continuity.

Comment: For every $a $ in $-\infty <a <\infty $ is there a respective $b$ in $-\pi/2 < b < \pi/2$ such that $b +\tan b =a $?  This is like asking if your $f^{-1} $ exists...

Comment: It follows completely from the facts that $\tan x$ is surjective there and $x$ is bounded there. Can you show these simpler facts?

Comment: @MPW You still need to use continuity here like [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) (otherwise it does not work e.g. for $x+\text{sign}\,(x)$ on ${\mathbb R}$).

Comment: @A.Γ.  Yes, agreed.